# Drag and drop is not working in WPF application after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: wpf

In my WPF project, one requirement needs drag and drop feature. Drag and drop was worked properly. It was developed in Visual studio 2010 in OS Windows 7. Now we upgrade our OS to Windows 10. Now the drag and drop feature is not working. The below events are used to implement drag and drop.

button.PreviewMouseMove, button.GiveFeedback

A ghost image is also created for drag effect.

Comment: I recommed you to upgrade application and use drag (and drop) events that was designated for that purpose. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/drag-and-drop-overview

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. What you mean by upgrading application? Drag and drop work in Windows 7, .Net 4 frame work. Now we upgrade 4.6.2 .Net frame work and Windows 10. It was working properly in Windows 7. Why stop working in Windows 10? Is there any system settings?